# HDMI not detected on Ubuntu 18.04 GTX1650 Asus

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I know that there are a lot of similiar topics, but I've read them all and none of them helped mi to solve the problem.
I have Asus Tuf Gaming fx505 with Geforce GTX1650, and my external monitor is not being detected. I'm using nvidia-driver-440, tried 435, 430, nouveau. I turned off secure boot as well.

Anyone know if it's possible to connect monitor via hdmi, I've tried everything.

Answer (score 2):

**Nvidia**

The recommended Nvidia driver for Gefore GTX1650 is 430.09. It can be downloaded at [here,](https://www.geforce.com/drivers) or [direct download](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/146629). Also, check your BIOS to assure that the hdmi port is properly enabled. Check if the hdmi port works under Windows. Check that in Ubuntu, the hdmi display is enabled in the Displays settings.

**BIOS**

In the `terminal`, do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and check your BIOS version. You have 308. It should be 310 to be current. The newer BIOS can be downloaded from [here.](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DD-DT-DU/HelpDesk_BIOS/) Assure good backups before updating your BIOS.

Comment: my bios version s 308, is it ok or it has to be 306?

Comment: I would normally say that newer is better, but the web site says that 306 is current, and it was only released on 3/12/2020. Contact ASUS support for more detail. Also, does the hdmi port work under Windows?

Comment: Assure that I've got the correct BIOS update page for your exact model #.

Comment: On official asus page the current bios is 310, should I update it? As I installed the 430, it detects the monitor, but it says "no signal" :(
And yes, the hdmi works on windows.

Comment: What ASUS page are you looking at? What EXACT model # do you have? And yes, after a good backup, I'd probably update your BIOS. Let me go look...

Comment: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DD-DT-DU/HelpDesk_Download/
My exact model is fx505dt

Comment: Yes, I see. 310 for your exact model #. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I don't know when, maybe after installing nvidia 430, I run into login loop, I can only login using Wayland, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @RobertSidzinka enter a console (ctrl-alt-f1) and type `ls -al ~/.*thority`.

Comment: I have two files, .Xauthority and .ICEauthority

Comment: @RobertSidzinka correct.

Comment: I tried chown on these files, chmod a+wt /tmp, sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
and still no luck

Comment: @RobertSidzinka They should be chown your_username:your_username, and chmod 600. And `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`.

Comment: it didn't help :/

Comment: @RobertSidzinka Darn Nvidia. Uninstall them, and get back to a working system. You can try a newer version if you like. Also, later, check the Displays settings panel, and make sure the hdmi 2nd monitor is enabled.

Comment: @RobertSidzinka try logging into another user account (create one if you need to) and see if anything is different.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: @RobertSidzinka Other than Nvidia driver problems, I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: @RobertSidzinka Status please. Did you ever update your BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-xconfig-doesnt-do-what-i-want-it-to-nor-does-nvidia-settings/107883/7

Main steps:

1. delete */etc/X11/xorg.conf*
2. modify */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf*

`Driver "amdgpu"` -> `Driver "modesetting"`

3. inside /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf add

`Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"`

4. create two files **optimus.desktop** in  */etc/xdg/autostart/* and */usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart/*  with content:

optimus.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Optimus
Exec=sh -c "xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0; xrandr --auto"
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=DisplayServer
```

After, function can be checked in terminal:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxinfo | grep vendor
```

The output should be something with `Nvidia`

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks, updated.

Comment: With this you will only use the nvidia GPU and need a lot of power...

Comment: Follow this at your own risk. I did this, and my computer blacks out…

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 20.04 and mainline 5.8 kernel all works fine for HDMI either with AMD GPU ou Nvidia GPU and Nvidia driver.

So you need a**bsolutely update to 5.8 Kernel**.

I wrote this for a computer with Ryzen 4800H and Geforce 1660 ; it will help you but is in french :
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/asus-a17-tuf66iu